# Upload Image and pdf file

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I have a project created with cms Django, and in this project i must upload a image and pdf file.
the code in models.py is as follow:

```
 file_pdf_fattura_finale_solo_amministrazione = models.FileField (upload_to = "/home/alessandro/Scrivania/progetto/static/finale/", max_length=20000,  blank=True)
```

The file with this step to upload, is inserted in correct folder, but the file not work.

In Administrator panel, when i click on image or pdf file, that i uploaded, the browser tell me Page not found (404). The current URL, home/alessandro/Scrivania/progetto/static/finale/header_blog.jpg, didn't match any of these.

I have verifed the permission, but i have in default chmod 777.

Any ideas?

I have follow also this tutorial youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQ7RAhaehs0&list=UUkLMlkrce5Ce_ujCWGuF5oA&index=18&feature=plcp 
I have the same code, but not result.

Any Ideas? Where is my error?

I can send the zip folder with the project, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try

```
file_pdf_fattura_finale_solo_amministrazione = models.FileField (upload_to = "static/finale", max_length=20000,  blank=True)
```

this would upload the files to the path 'static/finale' folder from the project root more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield)

Comment: Ok, i try it, but the error there is.Now,  I think what I not write correctly the configuration in settings.py.  Media_Root, Media_Url, Static_Root, Static_Url are empty. There parameters should not be empty, true? I developer in localhost (on Linux/Ubuntu), web server Apache. What should i write as configuration?

Comment: Because, with your solution, the result is: The object albax with primary key u'20/static/finale/Magic_green_bus_1.jpg' not exits.

Comment: Or in urls.py? Because, in urls.py the code are as follow: http://dpaste.com/793124/

Comment: The file settings.py is: http://dpaste.com/796111/

But the result is page not found, when i click on media file, that i upload.

any ideas?

Comment: Yes Alexander ur setting file is correct in the urls can u add this to handle the media files  url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:], 'django.views.static.serve',
       {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

Comment: Ok Rakesh, thanks, i add in urls.py, but the error now is: name 'settings' is not defined, :-( any ideas? Sorry, for my small knowledge in django.

Comment: in the settings.py add "from django.conf import settings"

Comment: all project? if yes, it's possible.